# Aggregating and calculating fractional vegetation cover from raster using R

Tags: raster, r, aggregation

I have some MODIS data on vegetation cover. It is at a 250 m resolution and I would like to aggregate the pixels on a 1 km scale, and at the same time calculate the fractional vegetation cover since I will downscale it. I tried to use [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262958/155292) to [Calculation of fractional cover for each vegetation class at 30-m resolution matching MODIS swath in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262015), but I eventually end up with one layer only summing up the fractional vegetation cover for one vegetation class on a 1 km scale and not the fractional cover of each individual vegetation type.

Here is the data:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 25658, 15349, 393824642  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 249.9999, 249.9999  (x, y)
extent     : -15191755, -11354506, 8399516, 14814014  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs 
values     : 1, 11  (min, max)
```

Here is the script:

```
library(raster)
s <- raster(path.tif)
s.fraction <- aggregate(x = s, 
                     fact = 4, 
         fun = function(x, ...)
   {(sum(x == 1, ...)/16)*100})

writeRaster(s.fraction, "path_fraction.tif")
```

I also have the data as a stack where each individual vegetation cover is located in 11 different bands.

Is that easier to calculate the fractional cover on a 1 km resolution than a single-band raster?

Multiband raster data is here:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 1  (of  11  bands)
dimensions : 25658, 15349, 393824642  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 249.9999, 249.9999  (x, y)
extent     : -15191755, -11354506, 8399516, 14814014  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs  
values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
```

How can I calculate the fractional vegetation cover for each vegetation class and put it in a multiband raster?

Comment: The code `land.cover.crop[land.cover.crop != 1] <- NA` is creating a raster with a single value, in this case 1. The expectation in the answer is that you create a raster for each class and apply the `aggregate` function accordingly.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense thanks. Back to my question. How can I then loop this into fitting data in a multiband raster?